# get value from textfield html into java variable

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am tring to run function that get 2 variables one of them should get the value from textfield.

any advice?

```
<%@page import="root.SQLQuery"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1255"
pageEncoding="windows-1255"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<%@ page import="root.SQLQuery"%>
<% 
String emp_email = session.getAttribute("email").toString();
SQLQuery sql = new SQLQuery();
String link="";

%>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<table width="900" height="900">
<iframe src="http://www.aol.com/av" width="900" height="900"></iframe>
<center>
<font color=red>your email is:<%=emp_email%>></font>
Copy the link here: <input type="text" name="videoLink" id="link">
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="<%sql.meetingUpdateVideoLink(emp_email,        request.getParameter("videoLink").toString()); %>>">
</center>

</table>
</center>
```

I am tring to insert the fanction meetingUpdateVideoLink() two variables:

1. email - that easy I get from session.
2. Link - that is the tricky one I need to get it from the textfield name="videoLink"

Thanks,
Cfir

Comment: Either the form has not been posted, in which case how are you able to know what's in the field, or it has been posted, in which case the field should be in your POST data. However, I note that you're not using a <form> tag here - why should your submit button send the text field if it is not part of a unified form?

Comment: I dont wont to submit a form because I don't want to refrash the page, is there a way to use javascript in order to get the Link

Comment: Can't understand the question *at all*, but using scriptlets instead of EL is wrong, and using server side scriptlet to generate client side onclick event is totally wrong :|